# Displaying zero values in spotfire data visualization

Tags: spotfire

I have months on x-axis and row count on y-axis. I wanted to display the 12 months jan-dec on x-axis as count 0 even if data is not present in data table. 
Can you please help me.

Thanks
Bharath

Comment: Did you figure this out? Is this related to your other post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859326/how-to-auto-select-filters-in-spotfire

Comment: I had to hardcoded the data in dataset as I did not find any other alternative. Beacuse at first point there is null values present for 3 months data. i had to insert 13 months and hard code as 0

Comment: ok, glad to know my comments on the answer below made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to Right Click on your Chart > Apperance > Check the box "Compensate for missing values". However, you can't use this with `ROWCOUNT()` on your Y-Axis. You will have to set it to something like `Count([YourUniqueIdColumn])`

Comment: My custom expression on y-axis is something like sum(x)/count(y) . I would like to have last 13 months data on categorical axes. i think Compensate for missing values will work if datatype is of date, but here my datatype is varchar something like Jul-16. is there any other way where i can show 0's for the months for which data is not present

Comment: I think you would be better suited creating a calculated column off of your varchar date field. something like Date([VarcharDate]) as Date and use this on your category axis. You can only show 0 for a category if there is explicitly 0 in the value or if you use a time series on the categorical axis. If you don't want to create the date column, you'll have to replace all NULL values with 0 in your dataset so it will show 0 versus nothing, which is what it does for NULL or missing values.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where my x-axis was a string (client name) and the y-axis was a uniquecount of another string. The above didn't work because, as mentioned, it only works if the values are 0 and not Null. The workaround I found was right clicking the x-axis text (not the hireracy) -> Categories -> Show All Values