# How to auto select filters in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have a list box filter in spotfire. Is it possible to auto select one of the values in the filter list. Ultimately when I filter on B, I should able to see data for both B and A(which was auto selected)

```
TASK,SERVICE,MONTHYEAR ARE MY FIELDS AND TOTALLY THERE ARE 15 RECORDS
TASK    SERVICE       MONTHYEAR
    NA        NOV-15
    NA        APR-16
TASK1   SERVICE1      JUL-15
    NA        SEP-15
    NA        DEC-15
    NA        FEB-16
TASK2   SERVICE2      AUG-15
    NA        JUL-16
    NA        MAR-16
    NA        JUN-16
    NA        OCT-15
    NA        JAN-16
    NA        MAY-16
    NA        JUL-15
    NA        AUG-15
```

As you can see in the above dataset data is present only for monthyear jul-15 and aug-15. I had to add the remaining 13 months and place NA in place of service which would display zero. Selection of this 'NA' is mandatory with any other filter to display the zero count. Is there any way to select 'NA' automatically, so that I can only filter on either 'service1' or 'service2' to display the result.

Comment: Can you explain further?  Is A always selected? What determines the auto selection?

Comment: what does automatic mean to you? when the document is opened? opened in Analyst or Web Player or both? is there a reason that saving with the filter selected doesn't work? you need to explain your question better.

Comment: I will explain you my requirement here. I need to display count for last 13 months, if data is not present for particular month then I have to display 0 as count. So I have hard coded those values for 0 in dataset with name 'A'. when i apply filter on any other value say B then  I should get the data for values A (which shows 0 count) and also for B. I have tried using configuration block, but the value that is set in URL is no more as soon as I apply any other from filter panel. can you please let me know if there is any other possible way. Thanks

Comment: Can you please attach a sample dataset. It's hard to understand what you have.

Comment: Please provide me your mail id.. I will send you the details. I am unable to attach anything here :)

Comment: Just click "edit" in your original post and paste some data from excel. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my original post. Thanks